# How to force function to await for jszip.loadAsync() function to execute?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, jszip

I`m relatively new to js and async/await stuff.
Trying to write a function that reads a zip archive and returns number of non-empty files, number of files overall and sum of their sizes.

```
const jszip = require('jszip')
const fs = require('fs')

async function Backup(path) {
    let files = 0
    let notEmpties = 0
    let size = 0
    fs.readFile(path, async (err, data) => {
        if (err) console.log(err)

        await jszip.loadAsync(data).then((zip) => {
            zip.forEach(async (path, file) => {
                files++
                await file.async('arraybuffer').then((data) => {
                    if (data.byteLength > 0) {
                        console.log(file.name, data.byteLength)
                        notEmpties++
                        size += data.byteLength
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    })
    return [notEmpties, files, size]
}
```

And the execution:

```
async function start(){
    return await Backup('C:\\Users\\Szymon\\Desktop\\(DOKUMENTY)20221027fbs083114601.zip')
}

//start
try {
    console.log(start());
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

But it outputs a pending promise instead of numbers array.
What`s even stranger to me is that it outputs a pending promise before it outputs all the console logs inside Backup() function, so all the 'awaits' inside Backup() function don't work as i expected.

Where am i wrong?

Already tried multiple combinations of async/await inside Backup().
Also tried to deal with it with .then():

```
async function Backup(path) {
    let files = 0
    let notEmpties = 0
    let size = 0
    fs.readFile(path, async (err, data) => {
        if (err) console.log(err)

        await jszip.loadAsync(data).then((zip) => {
            zip.forEach(async (path, file) => {
                files++
                await file.async('arraybuffer').then((data) => {
                    if (data.byteLength > 0) {
                        console.log(file.name, data.byteLength)
                        notEmpties++
                        size += data.byteLength
                    }
                })
            })
        }).then(() => {
            return [notEmpties, files, size]
        })
    })
}
```

but none of these seems to work.

Using Node.js v18.12.1

Comment: You have to await `zip.forEach`. If it returns a promise, you can simply add `await` in front of it. If it doesn't, you could promisify it. Is `zip` a basic JavaScript array?

Comment: Use `fs/promises` instead of `fs`.